# C++ classes and objects

Tags: c++, class

I am really new to c++ and i have a really quick question,

```
struct triplet {
 int first;
 int second;
 int third;
};


class mystery {

 private:
 int x;
 int y;
 struct triplet* the_triplet;
 public:
 mystery(int f, int s, int t);
 ~mystery();
 mystery & mystery_member(const mystery & other) const;

};
```

What does the line

```
mystery & mystery_member(const mystery & other) const;
```

mean or do?

Comment: It declares a const non-static member function on `mystery` that takes a `mystery const&` and returns a `mystery&`.

Comment: so what exactly does the &other represent?

Comment: @Andy The `&` says that a reference is passed as argument instead of a copy. The `other` is for readability. It should give a hint about what role the argument playes in the function. It is not required in the decleration of a function. In the implementation of a function, it's the variable that can be used to access the argument within the function body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mystery & mystery_member(const mystery & other) const` declares a member function of the `mystery` class that

- takes a reference to an object of type `mystery` as an argument (that's the `mystery & other` part),
- is not allowed to modify that object (that's the `const` in front of the `mystery & other` part),
- returns a reference to an object of type `mystery` (that's the `mystery &` part at the start),
- does not change any member variables of the object on which it is called (that's the `const` at the end).